# How to Choose Geoserver and GeowebCache Configuration Options?

Tags: geoserver, java, geowebcache, configuration

I have two Win 2008 R2 Servers currently dedicated to running one instance of Geoserver each. We are looking at setting up geowebcache.
Win Servers have 2Gb Ram and they do nothing but run Geoserver at the moment.
For practical purposes, I have 1Mb, maybe 1.2, to allocate to TomCat.

First, does anyone have any experience on how much Ram can be allocated to Geoserver/geoWebcache withoput impacting Windows Performance?

Second, which way should I set it up?

- Option 1: One server running GeowebCahe and one server running Geoserver.
- Option 2: Geoserver and geowebcache on each server.

Third, the Geowebcache documentation recommends allocating *at least* 256 Mb of heap memory. It would be reasonable to assume the more memory the better. If Option 2 is chosen, how should I apportion the available memory between Geoserver and GeoWebCache?

Fourth, am I better off running Geoserver in TomCat or in the environment it is distributed in?

Last, are there any pros and cons on performance for a JDK vs a JRE environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer here.  Have you seen the following resources?

http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/introduction/whichgwc.html

If you have one geoserver then use the integrated geowebcache otherwise use the standalone GWC to connect to multiple geoservers.

http://opengeo.org/publications/geoserver-production/

OpenGeo certainly recommend using the latest Oracle JRE JVM in server mode and the native JAI extensions.

Regarding memory it is also worthwhile looking at how your PostgreSQL/PostGIS database is configured as well as your JVM.  Settings like maintenance_work_mem, shared_buffers and work_mem will improve performance if set correctly.  See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: Hi mixedbredie, thanks. Yep, got the postgres and PostGis stuff covered.
I am messing with my geoserver instances as we speak (2.2.5) and every time I restart them I have to turn on the Geowebcache again. I have my services set to restart the computer and then I lose the geowebcache services, they default to disabled. That has been one of my problems. Will ask a separate question on this tomorrow when I have my facts straight.

Comment: Hi mixedbredie, there definitely is a problem running Geoserver and GeoWebcache. Question on this asked [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/geoserver-2-2-5-and-integrated-geowebcache-caching-defaults-not-saved-over-resta)