# Geoserver 2.2.5 and Integrated GeoWebcache caching Defaults not saved over restarts

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, configuration

I am experience an annoying issue with Geoserver 2.2.5 and the integrated GeoWebCache running as a service on Windows. The Caching Defaults Configuration is not retained over GeoServer Restarts or Server Reboots.

This is particularly annoying in a production Environment as a server reboot or *GeoServer Service Auto Restart on failure* ends up with GeoServer running with no cache at all.

We have our Service set to restart the service on failure, then reboot the computer automatically on the third failure.

The documentation points to a configuration file in the Geoserver data directory named *gwc-gs.xml* that holds the configuration details. No matter what we do by editing this file, we cannot get the configuration to persist.

Interestingly, I noticed that a file named *gwc-gs.xml.tmp* was also in the same location. When I delete this .tmp file and then restart Geoserver, it appears again, always containing the default values

So my assumption is that this *.tmp* file is being created on Geoserver start up and it is being read by the GeoWebCache code, not the actual *.xml* file.

Question: Has anyone else experienced this or know of this behavior?

Question: Does anyone know of a work around or know if this behavior has been corrected in a later version of Geoserver?

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: Is there anything in the geoserver log? What about upgrading geoserver to latest release? How are you running geoserver - in Tomcat/Jetty/standalone? I am running 2.3.3 in Tomcat7 and after a restart my log file has: 
2013-08-23 08:53:42,251 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
2013-08-23 08:53:42,360 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/gwc/service/**] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2013-08-23 08:53:42,468 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc) - GWC is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, Windows specific, has been fixed in the 2.3.x series: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-5536